# difference between cvCalcHist and calcHist

Tags: c++, c, histogram, opencv3.0

I'm trying to understand the difference between the `cvCalcHist`, the method to compute the histogram of an image in `openCV c version` and `calcHist`, the method to compute the histogram of an image in `openCV c++ version`.

`openCV c version code:`

```
    // load the color image
    IplImage* im = cvLoadImage("2.png");

    // get the color histogram
    IplImage* im32f = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(im), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 3);
    cvConvertScale(im, im32f);

    int histSize[] = {32, 32, 32};
    float rgbRange[] = {0, 256};
    float* ranges[] = {rgbRange, rgbRange, rgbRange};

    CvHistogram* hist = cvCreateHist(3, histSize, CV_HIST_ARRAY, ranges);
    IplImage* b = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(im32f), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
    IplImage* g = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(im32f), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
    IplImage* r = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(im32f), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);

    cvSplit(im32f, b, g, r, NULL);
    IplImage* planes[] = {b, g, r};
    cvCalcHist(planes, hist);

    // find min and max values of histogram bins
    float minval, maxval;
    cvGetMinMaxHistValue(hist, &minval, &maxval);
    cout << "Min : " << minval << " / Max : " << maxval << endl;

    //OUTPUT: Min : 0 / Max : 177617
```

`openCV c++ version code:`

```
    const int channels[] = {0, 1, 2};
    const int histSize[] = {32, 32, 32};
    const float rgbRange[] = {0, 256};
    const float* ranges[] = {rgbRange, rgbRange, rgbRange};
    Mat im = imread("2.png",IMREAD_COLOR);
    MatND hist;
    Mat im32fc3, backpr32f(im.cols, im.rows, CV_32F), backpr8u(im.cols, im.rows, CV_8U), backprBw;
    im.convertTo(im32fc3, CV_32F);

    // compute histogram, scale it to 0-255 range and backproject
    calcHist( &im32fc3, 1, channels, Mat(), hist, 1, histSize, ranges, true, false);
    // find min and max values of histogram bins
    double minval, maxval;
    cv::minMaxIdx(hist, &minval, &maxval);
    cout << "Min : " << minval << " / Max : " << maxval << endl;

    //OUTPUT: Min : 455 / Max : 476732
```

As you can see in the `//OUTPUT` comments in the code sections above, the values are different between the 2 pieces of code where I think I should get the same result. Any clue what is happening?

Comment: It seems to me that you calculate the histogram using `im32f` in the C version, but in the C++ version you are using `im` instead of `im32fc3`. Can you check that? (and you didn't post complete code, `channels` is not declared)

Comment: I tried it and got same results. @MatthäusBrandl

Comment: `calcHist( &im32fc3, 1, channels, Mat(), hist, 1, histSize, ranges, true, false);` should be `calcHist( &im32fc3, 1, channels, Mat(), hist, 3, histSize, ranges, true, false);` can you check this before I write an answer?

Comment: It fixed the problem, @Miki. But just one question about the results, what does this method exactly? Does it compute the histogram for each channel of the image separatly?

Comment: no, it computes a 3d histogram in R,G,B, each dimension with 32 bin, so a total of 32*32*32 bins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating a 3D histogram in B,G,R, you need to tell `calcHist` the correct number of dimension: 3. So basically you need to change from:

```
calcHist( &im32fc3, 1, channels, Mat(), hist, 1, histSize, ranges, true, false);
//                                            ^
//                                       one dimension
```

to this with correct number of dimensions:

```
calcHist( &im32fc3, 1, channels, Mat(), hist, 3, histSize, ranges, true, false);
//                                            ^
//                                       three dimensions
```